# Not able to create a new Force.com IDE project on macOS Mojave

Tags: visualforce, eclipse, force.com-ide

after I fill in all the required (username, password, security token and environment) and click "Next>" nothing happens :( No error even

Comment: Why force.com IDE, its getting depricated in 3 months, https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/12/the-future-of-salesforce-ides.html

Comment: I'm a newbie. This is the IDE used in our organization and this is what I've been told to install...